# Obtaining a de-focus event other than from Stage - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have a piece of code much like this:

```
package blah;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SimpleExample {

TextInputControl textFieldForWork;
LocalTextChangeListener localTextChangeListener;


public SimpleExample(TextInputControl textFieldForWork, Stage s) {
    this.textFieldForWork = textFieldForWork;
    localTextChangeListener = new LocalTextChangeListener();

    System.out.println("Creating new focus listener for TextField component");
    LocalFocusListener localFocusListener = new LocalFocusListener();

    s.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            if (observable.getValue().toString().equals("false")) {
                System.out.println("Removing TextField focus listener");
                textFieldForWork.focusedProperty().removeListener(localFocusListener);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Adding TextField focus listener");
                textFieldForWork.focusedProperty().addListener(localFocusListener);
            }
        }
    });
}

private class LocalFocusListener implements ChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        if (observable.getValue().toString().equals("true")) {
            System.out.println("Adding text change listener");
            textFieldForWork.textProperty().addListener(localTextChangeListener);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Removing text change listener");
            textFieldForWork.textProperty().removeListener(localTextChangeListener);
        }
    }
}

private class LocalTextChangeListener implements ChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        System.out.println("Textfield changed - do processing");
    }
}}
```

The purpose of this code is to fire a listener each time the user types something in the textfield. The other necessary function of this code, is that upon dialog defocus, the textfield listeners should be removed.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I really understand why you need to observe the focused property of the stage. Can't you just register the listener with the text field once and leave it there? It won't be invoked unless the text changes.

If you really need the functionality you describe, you can do it. Here's a description of what's going on:

The `focusedProperty` of the text field tracks whether or not the `Node` with focus within the current scene graph is the text field. It is "local to the scene graph", which means it is independent of whether or not the window is the active or focused window.

The `focusedProperty` of the window tracks whether or not the window has focus. This changes if you move the application to the background, etc.

Obviously, at the point where you create the text field, is hasn't been added to a scene or window, so just doing

`textFieldForWork.getScene().getWindow().focusedProperty().addListener(...)`

won't work, because `getScene()` will return `null` at this point. Even if the scene is non-null, it might not yet belong to a window, so you may have `getScene()` non-null but `getScene().getWindow()` null at some point.

So what you actually want to do is observe the sequence of properties. Start with `textFieldForWork.sceneProperty()` and observe it; if it changes and is non-null, then observe `textFieldForInput.getScene().windowProperty()`; when that changes and is non-null, observe `textFieldForInput.getScene().getWindow().focusedProperty()`.

You could handle this yourself, creating listeners for each step in the chain and adding and removing them as necessary, but the [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) framework has API that manages exactly this use case. Using EasyBind you can do

```
    MonadicObservableValue<Boolean> stageFocused = 
            EasyBind.monadic(textFieldForWork.sceneProperty())
                .flatMap(Scene::windowProperty)
                .flatMap(Window::focusedProperty)
                .orElse(false);
    stageFocused.addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
        if (isNowFocused) {
            // stage now has focus...
        } else {
            // stage has lost focus...
        }
    });
```

If you want to check the condition that the text field has focus *and* the window containing it has focus, you can do

```
BooleanBinding stageAndTextFieldFocused = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> 
    stageFocused.get() && tf.isFocused(),
    stageFocused, tf.focusedProperty());
```

with `stageFocused` as above. Then just do

```
stageAndTextFieldFocused.addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> 
    { /* etc ... */ });
```

Comment: Thanks.. Let me try to explain: What I'm working on is a Validation framework. Sometimes, my textfields live inside modal boxes that are inside a new Stage -- additionally, I use tabs in the main application, which also contain Textfields. In a few sentences: I want to watch my textfields for focus events using listeners-- On focus gain, I want to start textfield listeners-- But when their parent loses focus, remove those listeners, but without passing in Stage, Node or Tab parameters to my validation code.

Comment: The code I posted will let you do that. But I still don't know why you think you have to add and remove the listener on the text field as the window gains and loses focus. Why not just add the listener to the text field once and leave it there?

Comment: Hi James. When my application is running in the background, I want to kill off listeners as I assume these are hogging cpu, and if I defocus from the whole application e.g.[alt-tab] windows, and I have added listeners only to TextField elements, then no event is fired upon defocus.  For correct defocus it seems that I need to watch Stage. I've just checked to make sure I'm correct in this. Surely this is not correct behaviour by FX?

Comment: Why would they use CPU if the field has no focus? The listener is only invoked if the text changes.

Comment: Having thought about this, you're right: the listeners shouldn't be resource hogs. But what I'm left wondering is how your framework -- and I do appreciate your answer -- is different from .focusedProperty().addListener() ? Guess my question is a bit dumb, maybe I should delete it!

Comment: It's different from `textFieldForWork.focusedProperty().addListener(...)` because it tracks focus of the containing window, not the text field. It's different from `s.focusedProperty().addListener(...)` because you don't have to pass in a reference to the window (and, actually, will track whether or not the enclosing window has focus even if the text field is moved to a different window). I updated the answer for clarification of all these points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68597/discussion-between-wax-lyrical-and-james-d).